# Print License agreement in JSF

Tags: jsf, printing, xhtml

I am creating License Agreement page in JSF using xhtml. In there is a link "print license agreeement". In which, when the User clicks Print License Agreement,the license will be exported to a pdf, which the
user can then print. Can you please tell me how we do this in jsf?

Answer (score 0):

Following javascript function was used (years ago in JSF 1.2) for print *toPrint* part of page:

```
function printTandC() {
    if (isIE() == true){ 
        document.toPrint.focus(); 
        document.toPrint.print(); 
    } else { 
        window.frames['toPrint'].focus(); 
        window.frames['toPrint'].print();
    }
}
```

where `toPrint` was

```
<iframe src="../tandcprintable.seam" id="toPrint" name="toPrint" class="tandcprintable"/>
```